# Why are there no monadic operations in std::expected?

Tags: c++, c++23, std-expected

In C++23, monadic operations in `std::optional` was adopted, and later on `std::expected`. Why were monadic operations like `and_then`, `transform`, and `or_else` not included in the main paper?

Comment: I think they cover that in §11.2 of the latest proposal.

Comment: Was `expected` adopted for C++23?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, as of yesterday.

Comment: Meanwhile does exists an implementation with monadic enabled: https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: `std::expected` in C++23 will have monadic operations.

---

The `std::expected` proposal is very old. The adopted revision is P0323R12, which already suggests a long life, but that paper even predates the P-numbering system and started out as [N4015](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf), dated May 2014.

I bring this up because `std::expected`, even by itself, has taken a very long time to wind its way through the process. In contrast, the monadic operations for `std::optional` paper only first appeared in [October 2017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0798r0.html). And since then it was just a long slog just to get `std::expected` at all.

There *is* a paper proposing monadic operations for `std::expected`, that's [P2505R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2505r0.html), but at this point it's very incomplete and needs a lot of work. The design window for new C++23 features is closed, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were an NB comment requesting it in later anyway.

At least we finally have `std::expected`.

---

Coming in here a few months later, there was an NB comment requesting the monadic operators for `std::expected` and [P2505R5](https://wg21.link/p2505R5) was adopted for C++23 in Kona in November 2022.

Comment: For what it's worth, [P2505 seems to be on-track for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1161). At the very least, LWG seems to be open to considering it for C++23.

Comment: It looks like there's no `.transform_error`. That seems desirable. Or does `.or_else` handle that?

Comment: @Ben There is a `transform_error` now. Like I said, R0 of that paper was very incomplete.